How is the 5V forwarded to this Opamp?
I am trying to put together my own PCB and I am struggling really hard because I am working with through-hole components, and the swiss cheese resulting of my cramming a lot of components in makes it quite hard to draw tracks. Especially when microcontrollers are part of the PCB.
I went looking for inspiration from a project similar to mine and found this:

I can see that the linear voltage regulator L78L05 converts VCC to 5V for the TL072, however I do not see how that voltage is routed to the TL072 which is boxed inside of all the holes from the Daisy Seed microcontroller. I don't see how someone can draw a track on either side of the PCB without hitting the barrage of through holes. I tried looking for examples of people using this PCB on the internet, but the back of the PCB is never shown.
Is it a jumper wire that does the trick ?
Thank you very much.

There might be routing on the bottom side of the board, or on the inside. The schematic doesn't show how the power pins are routed either. its not possible to know for sure unless you have the proper board in front of you, I'd say.

But the holes of the Daisy Seed form a wall between the L78L05 and the TL072, and the holes are through holes. How could a routing work on the inside or the bottom if there are holes ?

@Arno You can fit a track between those holes.

You route between the holes, or on the right or left side of the row of holes?

It’s clearly a double-sided pcb as there are vias. Plenty of room to run tracks on the bottom side.

Ah ok. I was really assuming that the space between the holes are too tight to fit a track. Thanks a lot, that already clarifies things. The track would be conducting power though, is there a minimum track width I'd need to use to make sure enough current gets through ?

Current carrying capacity of a power trace would be another question, and one that has been asked several times on here already. I suggest a trip to the search box for that


Pin pitch for the Daisy Seed is 2.54mm. If you measure the screenshot you see that the pads for the pins are ~1.5mm. You have 1mm spacing between the end of one pin pad to the next, and 4 mm from the edge of the board to the leftmost pin of the Daisy Seed module.
If you were really craving space you could go for a fine trace/space of 100µm, you would be able to fit 4 traces between each pin, and 19 traces on the left side of the pins.
There is plenty of room for routing traces on this board.

(1 mm - 0.1mm)/(0.1 mm + 0.1 mm) = 4.5 traces
(4 mm - 0.1mm)/(0.1 mm + 0.1 mm) = 19.5 traces


Hello. Thank you very much for answering my question, and apologies if my concerns about track width were nooby. I'm happy to learn that routing between the pins is possible and that there is plenty of room for it. Thanks again.
